# How to test a function in jest and enzyme which is being called inside a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tdd, enzyme, jestjs

I have a function which looks like :

```
const generateCheckboxes = (array, filterType) => {
    return array.map((filter, i) => {
        if (!isNullOrUndefined(filter) && filter !== "") {
            const applied = props.appliedFilterList[filterType].includes(filter);
            return (
                <Row key={i} noLine={i === 0}>
                    <Checkbox checked={applied} onClick={() => props.toggleFilter(filterType, filter)}>
                        {filter}
                    </Checkbox>
                </Row>
            );
        }
        return false;
    });
};
```

and I am calling it as:

```
 return (
        <div>
            <div>
                {generateCheckboxes(props.accessFilters, "access")}
            </div>
            <div>
                {generateCheckboxes(props.bandwidthFilters, "bandwidth")}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
```

I want to test the function generateCheckboxes() using Jest and Enzyme. So, I have tried writing the  the following test case:

```
const accessFilters = ["Access Type Of The Service", { length: 1 }];
const bandwidthFilters = ["the allowed band width", "the allowed band width", { length: 2 }];

describe("test the component", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<FilterDropdownContent accessFilters={accessFilters} bandwidthFilters={bandwidthFilters} />);

    it("checks the generateCheckBoxes function", () => {
        expect(wrapper.instance.generateCheckboxes(accessFilters, "access").toBe(true));
    });
});
```

But I get the following error:

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'access' of undefined

      at array.map (src/site-product/components/FilterDropdownContent.js:12:105)
          at Array.map (<anonymous>)
```

and line 12 for the function in the component where I am getting the error is:

```
 const applied = props.appliedFilterList[filterType].includes(filter);
```

Can anyone please let me know where am i going wrong?

Comment: Please add more details.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems props.appliedFilterList returns undefined, so when trying to evauluate props.appliedFilterList[filterType] you get that error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'access' of undefined".

You need to pass appliedFilterList as a prop.

const appliedFilterList = // your appliedFilterList implementation

```
const wrapper = mount(<FilterDropdownContent accessFilters={accessFilters} bandwidthFilters={bandwidthFilters} appliedFilterList={appliedFilterList}/>);
```